# ROS-Error why is it occurring?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a tread before in which i had problems `roslaunch` flir_ptu_driver package, but now i am able to do so.. The problem is now connection to the PTU itself.

This problems occurs when it runs.

```
 SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
  * /ptu/ptu_driver/port: /dev/ttyS0
  * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
  * /rosdistro: indigo
  * /rosversion: 1.11.10

NODES   /ptu/
    ptu_driver (flir_ptu_driver/ptu_node)   /
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [22448]
process[ptu/ptu_driver-2]: started with pid [22471]
[ERROR] [1423666094.360529213]: Error getting pan-tilt res
[ERROR] [1423666094.567848519]: Error getting pan-tilt res
[ERROR] [1423666094.775231719]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666094.982708429]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666095.189972127]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666095.397236971]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666095.604498868]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666095.811768242]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666096.019039689]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666096.226318569]: Error getting pan-tilt limit
[ERROR] [1423666096.226392784]: Could not initialize FLIR PTU on /dev/ttyS0
```

It seems like that the first error messages  end, so they seem to resolve somehow, but the last one freezes and never gets resolved.  How come?...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202945/ros-error-why-is-it-occurring?/) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-02-11**:
I'm having the same problem at this very moment. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I 've been debugging the code and can see that during the initializing phase,  RX receives  garbage values..  eg. `write("px ")` returns |n8 and not a 7311. `pr` therefore get the value -1, and automatically lead  the boolean `initialize` to false, which is why it freezes.

--- Edit

problem resolved  baudrate was incorrect.

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-03**:
Can you be a bit more specific? I'm currently having the exact same problem. Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-04**:
The code is preset to run on a baud rate 9600. I changed that to one I had specified, and it worked.

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-04**:
Do you remember the baud rate you set ?

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-03-04**:
´stty -F /dev/ttyXX´ will tell you what your baud rate should be

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-04**:
Thanks for answering.
Still having the same error though. My question at ros answers can be found [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/204145/flir-46-70-connectivity-error/).